# PostgreSQL ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions, when it doesn't

Tags: postgresql

So I'm starting with this...

```
SELECT * FROM parts_finishing;
```

...I get this...

> id, id_part, id_finish, id_metal, id_description, date,
>   inside_hours_k, inside_rate, outside_material
>
> (0 rows)

...so everything looks fine so far so I do this...

```
INSERT INTO parts_finishing 
(
 id_part, id_finish, id_metal, id_description, 
 date, inside_hours_k, inside_rate, outside_material
) VALUES (
('1013', '6', '30', '1', NOW(), '0', '0', '22.43'), 
('1013', '6', '30', '2', NOW(), '0', '0', '32.45'));
```

...and I get...

> ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions

Now I've done a few things like ensuring numbers aren't in quotes, are in quotes (would love a table guide to that in regards to integers, numeric types, etc) *after* I obviously counted the number of column names and values being inserted. I also tried making sure that all the commas are commas...really at a loss here. There are no other columns except for `id` which is the `bigserial` `primary key`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Remove the extra `()` :

```
INSERT INTO parts_finishing 
(
 id_part, id_finish, id_metal, id_description, 
 date, inside_hours_k, inside_rate, outside_material
) VALUES 
  ('1013', '6', '30', '1', NOW(), '0', '0', '22.43')
, ('1013', '6', '30', '2', NOW(), '0', '0', '32.45')
  ;
```

---

the `(..., ...)` in Postgres is the syntax for a *tuple literal*; The extra set of `(` `)` would create a tuple of tuples, which makes no sense.

Also: for numeric literals you don't want the quotes:

```
(1013, 6, 30, 1, NOW(), 0, 0, 22.43)
, ...
```

, assuming all these types are numerical.

Comment: dDBeaver exports data with these extra parentesis

Comment: Such a simple thing, but it seems like the () should be a valid syntax... oh well, glad I fixed my very similar problem.

Comment: The extra `()` *are* valid syntax. Only the *semantics* are different.

Answer (score 37):

I had a similar problem when using **SQL** string composition with `psycopg2` in **Python**, but the problem was slightly different. I was missing a comma after one of the fields.

```
INSERT INTO parts_finishing
(id_part, id_finish, id_metal)
VALUES (
    %(id_part)s <-------------------- missing comma
    %(id_finish)s,
    %(id_metal)s
);
```

This caused `psycopg2` to yield this error:

> ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me in a large insert, everything was ok (comma-wise), it took me a while to notice I was inserting in the **wrong table** of course the DB does not know your intentions.
Copy-paste is the root of all evil ... :-)

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue as well.It will be raised, when the count of columns given and column values given is mismatched.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error on express js with PostgreSQL

I Solved it. This is my answer.

error fire at the time of inserting record.

> error occurred due to invalid column name with values passing
>
> error: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
>
> ERROR :  error: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
>   name: 'error',
>     length: 116,
>     severity: 'ERROR',
>     code: '42601',
>     detail: undefined,
>     hint: undefined,
>     position: '294',
>     internalPosition: undefined,
>     internalQuery: undefined,
>     where: undefined,
>     schema: undefined,
>     table: undefined,
>     column: undefined,
>     dataType: undefined,
>     constraint: undefined,
>     file: 'analyze.c',
>     line: '945',

here is my code dome

```
INSERT INTO student(
  first_name, last_name, email, phone
) 
VALUES 
  ($1, $2, $3, $4), 
values 
  : [ first_name, 
  last_name, 
  email, 
  phone ]
```

Comment: I’m confused by this answer. Are you saying you are currently having this problem? Or are you posting this code as a proposed solution?

Comment: I posted an answer

Comment: please [edit] your answer to make it look more like an answer

Answer (score -3):

IN my case there was syntax error in sub query.