# Postgres Error : syntax error at or near "("

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting this error

---

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "("Position: 65```

---

for the following query

---

```
insert into  Employee(no,name,phone) values ((1,Kenit,999999999)(2,Kenit,999999999)(3,Kenit,999999999)(4,Kenit,999999999)(5,Kenit,999999999)(6,Kenit,999999999))
```

Comment: You need to quote your string values, remove double `()` from values and add `,` after each values sequence

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27639296/905902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need commas between paranthesis for each record. And "Kenit" should be in quotes

```
insert into  Employee(no,name,phone) values ((1,'Kenit',999999999),
(2,'Kenit',999999999),(3,'Kenit',999999999),(4,'Kenit',999999999),
(5,'Kenit',999999999),(6,'Kenit',999999999))
```

Comment: Thanks, man, it helped I forgot commas in between two records.

Comment: @KenitPatel The outer most pair of parentheses is not needed for the VALUES clause. so `values (1, ...), (2, ...)` is enogh

Answer (score 0):

Try googling.
Source: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

```
INSERT INTO Employee (no,name,phone) VALUES ((1,Kenit,999999999),(2,Kenit,999999999),(3,Kenit,999999999),(4,Kenit,999999999),(5,Kenit,999999999),(6,Kenit,999999999));
```

happy to help

also: phone numbers should be saved in strings, as well as your names. so adding quotation marks helps not only in readability of the code it gives required LOGIC:

example:

```
...('asdf', 123, '+8920841209')
```