# Why I am getting Insert has more target columns than expressions

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a simple table called source with 3 columns (source_id, name, tenant_id) and some data in it.
I a trying to insert a data into the table by checking its existence in the table. But I am getting this error ..any idea how to resolve

The Query -

```
INSERT INTO moa.source(source_id, name, tenant_id)
    SELECT ((select max(source_id)+1 from moa.source), 'GE OWS - LHR', 1)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM moa.source where name = 'GE OWS - LHR');
```

The Error :

```
ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 1: INSERT INTO moa.source(source_id, name, tenant_id)
                                          ^
HINT:  The insertion source is a row expression containing the same number of columns expected by the INSERT. Did you accidentally use extra parentheses?
SQL state: 42
```

The Table:

[image]

Comment: `SELECT ((select max(source_id)+1 from moa.source), 'GE OWS - LHR', 1)` returns 1 column, which has 3 fields. (Remove the parentheses enclosing the select list to get separate columns.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions, when it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639239/postgresql-error-insert-has-more-target-columns-than-expressions-when-it-doesn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry..figured it out..there should be no paranthesis after Select